# How to use a RedirectResponse with a # (hash)?

Tags: 8, redirection

I have this code:

```
$event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse(base_path().'mypage#actions_clicker'));
```

It redirects to /mypage, but it doesn not include the #actions_clicker part. How do I make Drupal not loose the hash / # part?

Answer (score 1):

Try url encoding the `#` fragment. so it becomes `%23`, e.g:

```
$event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse(base_path().'mypage%23actions_clicker'));
```

**Update:**

Check the browser header to see that the fragment is passed. In my local testing it was ok:

**Sample code to append fragment to redirect response.**

```
return new RedirectResponse($redirect_url . '#test', 301);
```

[image: Location header includes fragment]

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2305927/583715

Comment: Says "Access denied". I.e. Drupal doesnt like that path.

Comment: Ah ok, urlencoding `#` to `%23` has worked for a couple of cases for me. Recently, when encoding the `destination` parameter. Generally `#` should be valid in the redirect URL, as per the http spec, but you may need to inspect the request with `curl` or similar to check the http requests and responses + headers there. In my local test, I could also pass `#actions_clicker` from `RedirectResponse` ok there

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but if it helps someone :

```
$event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse(Url::fromUri('mypage', ['fragment' => 'actions_clicker'));
```

Or with a route :

```
RedirectResponse(Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => $node->id()], ['fragment' => 'my-anchor'])->toString());
```

Note: `Url` is from namespace `\Drupal\Core\Url`